# TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, windows-8

I'm trying to execute the following command in a Node.js project on Windows 8:

> npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.24

But I'm gettig an error that I have node idea how to deal with.

> TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot
>   find the file specified. [C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt\build\copied_files.vcxproj]

Here is the entire output:

> > scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt
> >     node node-scrypt-preinstall.js
> >
> > scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined
>   npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-g
>   yp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild ) Warning: Missing input
>   files: C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt\build..\scrypt\win\include\config.h
>   Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable
>   parallel build, please add the "/m" switch. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5):
>   warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the
>   registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion  or PlatformToolset may be set to an
>   invalid version number. [C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt\build\copied_files.vcxproj]   Copying
>   scrypt/win/include/config.h to scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/config.h   The
>   system cannot find the file specified. TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed
>   to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.
>   [C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt\build\copied_files.vcxproj]
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5):
>   warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the
>   registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion  or PlatformToolset may be set to an
>   invalid version number. [C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt_wrapper.vcxproj] TRACKER :
>   error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the
>   file specified. [C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt_wrapper.vcxproj]
>
> gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\scrypt gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp
>   -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok npm WARN inbanner@1.6.0 No repository field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3
>   install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-11-13T01_31_12_133Z-debug.log

Help!

Comment: install CL.exe if not and then go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kezkeayy.aspx to set the enviroment variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This packages seems to be requiring native compiling. You need to install Visual Studio C++ Build Tools for the same. You can download the same from below link

http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Also after that you need to make sure that `CL.exe` is available in your path. It would be on a path like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ce\bin`. This would change based on the version of build tools you have installed.

You will need to make sure to update your Windows PATH environment variable if the setup doesn't do that for you.

Also if npm still fails, you can always try using `yarn`

```
yarn add web3@1.0.0-beta.24
```

Comment: I downloaded Visual C++ Build Tools, but when I open the file it just gets stuck

Comment: I've installed yarn but when I type to command you wrote, I receive: 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: How did you install it? You should use `npm install -g yarn`

Comment: I downloaded visual-cpp-build-tools 2017 and ran the setup and it said that it was installed successfully but for some reason I don't have a file named CL.exe on my computer.

Comment: Running yarn add web3@1.0.0-beta.24 produces an error while internally trying to run node-gyp rebuild, and it doesn't elaborate what the error is

Comment: Try defining a environment variable `NODE_DEBUG` with value as `fs,module` and then run the installation. That will give more debug logs

Comment: Finally I managed to install Visual C++ Build Tools. For some reason I had to uninstall Visual Studio first and then install it.

Comment: This link is broken: https://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools, but the Visual C++ Build Tools are now included in VS2017, see [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-build-tools-now-include-the-vs2017-and-vs2015-msvc-toolsets/)

Answer (score 2):

> ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.

The error is caused by the `scrypt` package because `node-gyp` is unable to rebuild,

try running **cmd** as administrator and run `npm install scrypt@6.0.3` , if it doesn't work try `node-gyp rebuild` or  [reinstall it](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)

if you fix your issue with node-gyp you should have `Cl.exe` at the right place in the process of installing `node-gyp`

Comment: I downloaded visual-cpp-build-tools 2017 and ran the setup and it said that it was installed successfully but for some reason I don't have a file named CL.exe on my computer.

Comment: Running node-gyp rebuild produces an error and it doesn't elaborate what the error is

Comment: `node-gyp rebuild --verbose` should be more detailed

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't elaborate in the error part

Comment: try `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` , did you try to reinstall `node-gyp` following instructions in the link ? , after some research, i guess you need to install `visual-cpp-build-tools 2015` not `2017`

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same boat and most of the answers found online couldn't help (or not 100% workable)with this rebuild error.  After trying on several different methods, I found this way works on my machine (Windows 10 Pro).  Now, I'm able to install web3 with no issue. (Or other packages related to node-gyp issues, such as "truffle unbox react")

The steps I concluded is as below:

1. Install NodeJS, Git
2. Download Windows Visual Studio 2015
3. Open Visual Studio 2015 and create "new project..."

   - Select "Create new C++ project"
   - You should see a menu that VS requested to install "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" and "Windows 8.1 SDK and Universal CRT SDK" (some processes in scrypt required tools from this Windows 8.1 SDK files)
   - Select both and install
4. Install/link python through npm command

   - `npm --add-python-to-path="true" --debug install --global windows-build-tools`
5. Set msvs_version to 2015

   - `npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global`
6. Install web3

   - `npm install web3`

For the reference: 
My npm version : 5.6.0
My node version: 8.9.4

Hope this would help!