# TS2306: './web3' is not a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module, ethereum

I try to use web3.js in my project.

Since I don't manage to install it, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256033/tracker-error-trk0005-failed-to-locate-cl-exe-the-system-cannot-find-the), I try a workaround in which I add the web.js file directly to my project and try to import it.

My code:

```
import * as Web3 from "./web3"
```

produces a TypeScript error:

> TS2306: './web3' is not a module

and at run time, Web3 equals to an empty object.

[Here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/dist/web3.js) is the source of web3.js file.

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

web3.d.ts:

```
declare module web3 {
    interface Web3 {
       foo(): void; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @msanford here is, I've added it

Comment: Thanks. And if you add `"moduleResolution": "node",` to tsconfig's `compilerOptions` ?

Comment: @msanford then there is no change

Comment: How about `import * as Web3 from "web3"` (remove the `./`)?

Comment: @msanford no, because web3 isn't installed in node_modules. It's just located in the same directory as a normal js library in the project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript ES6 import module "File is not a module error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805559/typescript-es6-import-module-file-is-not-a-module-error)

Answer (score 0):

umm looks like TypeScript cannot find a module named "web3", this is likely because the file "web3.js" is not exporting anything

try adding `module.exports = Web3;` to the end of your web3.js file to export the module and see if it helps